# Spring security: what function does AuthenticationManager.authenticate() perform

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have been studying Spring security with JWT for a while and i noticed that at every tutorial I read, the username and password is taken, wrapped in a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and passed on to a AuthenticationManager.authenticate() somthinglike this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.route.authentication.path}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws AuthenticationException {

    authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

    // Reload password post-security so we can generate the token
    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    // Return the token
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
}
```

my question is what does the authenticate method do, why is it used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-authentication-manager):

> AuthenticationManager is just an interface, so the implementation can be anything we choose. (...) The default implementation in Spring Security is called ProviderManager and rather than handling the authentication request itself, it delegates to a list of configured AuthenticationProviders, each of which is queried in turn to see if it can perform the authentication. Each provider will either throw an exception or return a fully populated Authentication object.